# Using GestureDetector inside InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Is it possible to use GestureDetector — specifically the onTapUp gesture — inside of an InteractiveViewer?

I know InteractiveViewer uses a GestureDetector itself and overrides the onScaleEnd, onScaleStart, and onScaleUpdate methods to implement panning. However, onTapUp is not overriden, which makes me think there's potential to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I did some digging around and found this in the [InteractiveViewer's TransformationController documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransformationController/toScene.html) for the *toScene()* method:

> Return the scene point at the given viewport point.
>
> A viewport point is relative to the parent while a scene point is
> relative to the child, regardless of transformation. Calling toScene
> with a viewport point essentially returns the scene coordinate that
> lies underneath the viewport point given the transform.
>
> The viewport transforms as the inverse of the child (i.e. moving the
> child left is equivalent to moving the viewport right).
>
> This method is often useful when determining where an event on the
> parent occurs on the child. This example shows how to determine where
> a tap on the parent occurred on the child.
>
> ```dart
> GestureDetector(
>     onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
>       _childWasTappedAt = _transformationController.toScene(
>         details.localPosition,
>       );
>     },
>     child: InteractiveViewer(
>       transformationController: _transformationController,
>       child: child,
>     ),   ); }
> ```

So it seems that rather than having a GestureDetector as a child, the recommended solution is to wrap the InteractiveViewer with a GestureDetector, use a custom TransformationController, and get the position relative to the viewer viewport from this controller.